# Items in CheckListBox are not showing up

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using CheckListBox item from WPF Extended Toolkit (https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckListBox) and I am trying to list some checkbox items but it is not working.

Here is my XAML:

```
<xctk:WizardPage
            x:Name="IntroPage"
            Title="Welcome"
            Description="This Wizard will walk you though something.">
            <xctk:CheckListBox
                Command="{Binding FeatureSelectedCommand}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Features}"
                SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding JustSelectedFeatures}" />
... etc
```

And here is my .cs code:

```
public partial class WizardWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Features { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> JustSelectedFeatures { get; set; }

    public WizardWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Features = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string>(new string[] {
                "item1",
                "item2",
                "item3"}));

        JustSelectedFeatures = new ObservableCollection<string>(Features);
    }

    ... etc
```

Why is the CheckListBox not updating with the three items? The list Features should be updating the CheckListBox but it doesn't and I have no idea why.

Comment: The expression `ItemsSource="{Binding Features}"` requires that the DataContext of the CheckListBox contains the source object of the binding, i.e. an instance of the class with the Features property. The value of the DataContext is usually inherited from the parent Window or Page. Since here the Window/Page is also the class that owns the source property, set `DataContext = this;` in the Window/Page constructor.

Comment: It works after adding `DataContext = this`, thank you!